# Can't read time series data into a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have been trying to create a time series dataset from a .csv file.

What I can't get around is that it has 2 time indexes: respectively the transaction date and the time, stored in two separate strings.

When trying this:

```
Date, Time, Open,High,Low,Close,Volume = np.loadtxt('EURUSD.txt', unpack = True,
                                delimiter = '\t',
                                converters = {0:time.strptime('%Y.%m.%d')})
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 00:00
```

which makes me suspect that the problem is the second time index.

The data looks like that:

```
2009.03.10  00:00   1.26185 1.26265 1.26185 1.2623  1344
2009.03.10  00:05   1.2623  1.26255 1.26185 1.26195 1656
2009.03.10  00:10   1.262   1.2622  1.26155 1.26175 1068
```

Where the first and the second column are the transaction date and the time, respectively. They are separated by tab.

Should I try and combine the two into one index? If so, how? I hope I explained my problem enough, I am entirely new to python and I have been trying to fix this for days now. If you have any questions, please feel free to ask and I will edit the post.

Comment: You need a converter from column 1 as well.  You can merge the `Date` and `Time` arrays after loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comments are easy, complete answers are what you are looking for here @Trebled.*

Anyways, as @hpaulj mentioned, **a converter to appropriately parse the datetime columns is needed** of your data. I usually do these kind of input/output operations using [pandas' read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv) function. But before that I recommend the addition of a header at the top of your data file (based on your question).

```
Date    Time    Open    High    Low Close   Volume
2009.03.10  00:00   1.26185 1.26265 1.26185 1.2623  1344
2009.03.10  00:05   1.2623  1.26255 1.26185 1.26195 1656
2009.03.10  00:10   1.262   1.2622  1.26155 1.26175 1068
```

Reading this file is a simple as calling:

```
from datetime import datetime # for parsing the Date and Time columns
import pandas as pd # for reading the data file

converters_ = {
    "Date": lambda value: datetime.strptime(value, "%Y.%m.%d").date(),
    "Time": lambda value: datetime.strptime(value, "%H:%M").time()
}

data = pd.read_csv('{file_name_goes_here}', sep='\t', header = 0, converters=converters_, dtype="float")
```

As you can see, the imports are for the appropriate function calls. Then, a dictionary is defined containing the converters for the Date and Time columns of the data. In this case, the converters are [lambda functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) that get the i-th value of the specified column and convert it to the corresponding datetime object through the [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html). This function receives the value and the specific [format](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-format-dates-in-python/) as arguments. Finally, the data is read from the file using the read_csv function with the necessary arguments separator (tabs), header (first line contains the keys for each column), converters, and dtype (set to float to convert all the other column values to floating point numbers).

Calling **data** will output:

```
>>> data
         Date      Time     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
0  2009-03-10  00:00:00  1.26185  1.26265  1.26185  1.26230    1344
1  2009-03-10  00:05:00  1.26230  1.26255  1.26185  1.26195    1656
2  2009-03-10  00:10:00  1.26200  1.26220  1.26155  1.26175    1068
```

In case you need to get the values of a specific column, make the call **data['{key}']**. For example, calling **data['Volume']** will output:

```
>>> data['Volume']
0    1344
1    1656
2    1068
Name: Volume, dtype: int64
```

If you even need the data as a numpy array, make the call **data['{key}'].values** For example, calling **data['Volume']** will output:

```
>>> data['Volume'].values
array([1344, 1656, 1068])
```

Finally if you want to read the Date and Time columns as one column:

```
from datetime import datetime # for parsing the Date and Time columns
import pandas as pd # for reading the data file

data = pd.read_csv('data.example', sep='\t', header = 0, parse_dates=[["Date", "Time"]], dtype = float)
```

In this case, no converters are needed as it the columns that should be parsed are being specified in a list for the *parse_dates* argument. Calling **data** will output:

```
>>> data
            Date_Time     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
0 2009-03-10 00:00:00  1.26185  1.26265  1.26185  1.26230    1344
1 2009-03-10 00:05:00  1.26230  1.26255  1.26185  1.26195    1656
2 2009-03-10 00:10:00  1.26200  1.26220  1.26155  1.26175    1068
```

I hope this answers your question. Feel free to ask me any question. Good luck!